# Density of tensor products in mixed Lebesgue spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, tensor-products

my question is the following: for $0<p,q<\infty$, define (I know the notation is not the usual one)
\begin{equation}
L^p(\mathbb{R}^m)\otimes L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)
\end{equation}
as the space of linear combinations of functions in the form $f\otimes g(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$, $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^m)$ and $g\in L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$.  What do we know about the density of this space in $L^{p,q}(\mathbb{R}^{n+m})$? For $p=q$ the density shall hold, but I can't find any reference for the general case. Moreover, I wonder if something is known for the weighted case.